# Separando proyectos de una solución en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estoy haciendo una proyecto el cual crecerá bastante, por lo que he decidido separar en proyectos toda la lógica de la solución.

Al crear un proyecto MVC. Visual Studio crea las carpetas Controller,Models y Views. Por lo que he decidido separar la solución en los siguientes proyectos.

Controladores, Database, Entidades, Models, ServiciosExternos, Views (Principal)

Esta solución tiene las siguientes referencias:

-Controller
    Database
    Entities
    Models
    Proxies

-Database
    Entities
    Proxies

-Entities

-Models
    Database
    Entities
    Proxies

-ServicesExt
    Entities

-Web(View)

El problema es el siguiente. Si tengo en el controlador una petición la cual devuelve unos datos consultados en databae, tengo que hacer las siguientes conversiones. Controlador -> Modelo -> Database -> Entities. La idea sería no utilizar las entidades y poder hacer directamente Controlador -> Modelo -> Database pero claro conforme tengo ahora mismo las relaciones, el proyecto database no tiene relacionado el modelo.

¿Como separariais el proyecto? Muchas gracias y un saludo

**Editado:** Para la persistencia de datos no utilizararé entity framework.

Gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: como vas a implementar el acceso a datos? usaras entity framework

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Desgraciadamente, asi como esta, la pregunta esta basada en opiniones. trata de arreglarla para que no sea asi, si no terminara cerrada.

Comment: y si creas nuevas soluciones y simplemente añades los archivos que quieres que sean parte de cada solucion y al final todos pueden ser recompilados de la solucion original

Answer (score 0):

No tienes que hacer la separacion tan completa, el modelo de la view lo defines en el mismo proyecto mvc, despues si separas el modelo de persistencia que sara entity framework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La carpeta `Dtos` defina las clases que usa mvc, utilizando `automapper` puede convertir facilmente de un model de persistencia.

En la primer parte de esta presentacion explico sobre la estructura del proyecto simple usando entity framework

[Integrando Angular con Asp.net Core](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5hJg0lRmfo)

Answer (score 0):

Se me olvidó comentar en el primer mensaje (Editado) que para la persistencia de datos no utilizararé entity framework. Por lo que para la conexión realizaré manualmente mediante clases con select e insert.

Gracias por las respuestas.